# Vue or Webpack compiled JS Cache Management

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have a question about webpack or compiled vue files and its cache management.
Somehow the browser knows when to fetch the app.js files when there is a new compiled version. When none then uses the Cache (or theres a 200B only download to it).

I would like to know the mechanism behind the automatic detecting of the js file.
Is it a feature of webpack? or vue?

Thanks IA

Answer (score 1):

Hot reloading is a feature of vue-cli, implemented using Webpack.

From the docs,

> When scaffolding the project with vue-cli, Hot Reload is enabled out-of-the-box.

When you're developing with Vue locally, Webpack is typically in [Watch Mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watch), which means it detects changes to your files and recompiles automatically.

How the DOM refreshes depends which part of the Vue component you have changed.

If you change the Template portion of a component, it will re-render without reloading because the component's internal state has not changed.

If you change the Script portion of a component, the component will reload.

[More info about Vue's hot reload](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/hot-reload.html#state-preservation-rules)

As for the app.js file, you'll see it's actually the **initiator** of the requests for the DOM diff, which run every time you save changes to your Vue files.

When you save a file, `[hash].hot-update.json` is requested. If `[hash].hot-update.json` has a non-empty payload, DOM-affecting changes have been detected. The DOM diff is then requested and applied as a patch via `app.[hash].hot-update.js`.

[image]

Comment: I see, Thanks for explaining concepts of webpack.